# What is the relation between Universality and simulations of Cellular Automata structures?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, cellular-automata

[Elementary Cellular Automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_cellular_automaton) and [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) show interesting Cellular structures, suppose we have a computational model {a Cellular Auotmaton} that can simulate both CA types (ECA & Conway's Game of life) from one input.

Meaning that, if we had a system with an input of (x), (x) can show a structure to an ECA rule {like rule 90} and that system by somehow can transform the input (x) when specified, to show similar patterns like in Conway's Game of life, how this would be related to universality in terms of simulations?

What about complexity, can be related also?

Comment: I can't understand the question.  Can you make it more precise?  I don't know what "show a structure to an ECA rule" would mean, nor what is meant by "that system can transform the input (x) to show similar patterns like in Conway's Game of life".  I also don't know "how would this be related to universality in terms of simulations" means -- what's "this", and what is meant by the "in terms of simulations" qualifier?  Try breaking that sentence down into smaller pieces, and give a mathematical definition of each concept/phrase you use before you use it.

Comment: A small note: If you've created multiple accounts on this site, I encourage you to merge them (see [instructions here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)).  It is generally discouraged to have multiple accounts, as that makes it easy to inadvertently violate rules regarding sock puppets / multiple accounts.